# PageControl Multiple Build error

Tags: iphone

I have downloaded apple's PageControl sample code and it will not run because i keep getting this warning "Multiple build commands for this file" Has anyone solved this? I am using xCode 3.2.5

Comment: I guess thats because there are 2 images with the same filename (Default.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove one of the 2 images named Default.png from the project, there is no warning anymore.